# Not able change FB Login button title

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I have a Facebook login view in registration page. May i know how to change the "Log in with Facebook" title to "Register with Facebook.

I tried to use the code below but not work.

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];

loginButton.center = self.view.center;


loginButton.readPermissions= @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
loginButton.delegate=self;

if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
{
    if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 || (int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
    {
        loginButton.frame=CGRectMake(26, 450, 270, 50);
    }
    else if((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667)
    {
        loginButton.frame=CGRectMake(26, 450, 270, 50);
    }
    else
    {
        loginButton.frame=CGRectMake(26, 450, 270, 50);
    }
}


[loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[loginButton setTitle:@"Register to Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

I'm not using custom view for that the button.

Comment: have you referenced the loginButton from FBLoginView subviews?

Comment: FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    
    loginButton.readPermissions= @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    loginButton.delegate=self;

Comment: could you edit the question and add the code to it, it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to change the title of button

```
 FBLoginView *loginView =
[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
 @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];
loginView.delegate = self;
loginView.frame =CGRectMake(10, submitBtn.frame.origin.y+40, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20, 50);
[self.view addSubview:loginView];for (id obj in self.loginView.subviews)
{
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {

                   UILabel * loginLabel =  obj;
                  loginLabel.text = @"Register with Facebook";
                   loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    }}
```

please let me know if any more information u want

Comment: i don't have FBLoginView. it show undeclared identifier. i had insert FBSDKLoginKit.framework, FBSDKCoreKit.framework, FBSDKShareKit.framework.